# handling gestureRecognizers on a custom UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c

I am adding gesture recognizers to my own subclass of UIView. In the recognizer handling method, I can access recognizer.view.

How can I cast this as my own UIView subclass, so that I can access its custom properties from within this method?

I'm adding the recognizer like so

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

And the method stub is

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyCustomView *recognizerView = (MyCustomView *) [panRecognizer view];
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that go inside the handle method?